# Valign Text Within A Hyperlink List Block Nav

Tags: html, css

http://cssdesk.com/sv2Wq

I'm trying to vertically align the text in respective `<li>`. The way I built it it doesn't really seem possible to do since the box itself is the link.

This is the standard way to do a simple navbar, right?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<title>
</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="navbar">
<ul>
<li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="news.php">News</a></li>
<li><a href="roster.php">Roster</a></li>
<li><a href="forums.php">Forums</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
</ul> 
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

--

```css
body, div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre, form, fieldset, input,textarea, p, blockquote, th, td {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

body {
background-image:url("images/gradients/background_gradient.png");
}

#wrapper {
margin: auto;
min-height: 1152px;
width: 1536px;
}

#navbar {
border: 1px solid red;
height: 200px;
width: 100%;
font-size: 2em;
margin: 0;
}

#navbar a {
text-decoration: none;
}

#navbar ul {
display: block;
list-style-type: none;
}

#navbar ul li a {
float: left;
display: block;
height: 200px;
width: 20%;
text-align: center;
letter-spacing: -0.5px;
}

#navbar ul li :hover{
background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible - just add `line-height`

```css
#navbar ul li a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    letter-spacing: -0.5px;
    line-height: 200px; /* this */
    text-align: center;
    width: 20%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the line-height of the anchor to the same value as the height of the list element.

edit: too slow :)

Oh, by the way: this just works as long as your links are on one line.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to center in html boxes vertically. Works amazing with me.
make sure it is in the link css.

```
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
```

Here is it in the css...

```
#navbar ul li a {
float: left;
height: 200px;
width: 20%;
text-align: center;
letter-spacing: -0.5px;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```